# New parent process when the parent process dies

Tags: process, init, exit

In UNIX, when a parent process disappears, I thought that all child processes reset init as their parent. Is this not correct all the time? Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.... I don't believe there are exceptions.

Found this "sometimes the parent process is killed before its child is killed. In this case, the "parent of all processes," `init` process, becomes the new PPID (parent process ID). Sometime these processes are called orphan process." [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-processes.htm)

Similarly is described in IBM's [blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/an_overview_of_linux_processes21?lang=en): "The parent dies or gets killed before the child. 
In the above scenario, the child process becomes the orphan process (as it has lost its parent). In Linux, the `init` process comes to the rescue of the orphan processes and adopts them. This means after a child has lost its parent, the `init` process becomes its new parent process."

Answer (score 83):

Three answers written in 2014, all saying that in Unices and in Linux the process is reparented to process #1 without exception.  Three wrong answers.  ☺

As the [SUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification) says, quoted in one of the [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149339/1174) answers here so I won't quote it again, the parent process of orphaned children is set to an *implementation-defined* process.  Cristian Ciupitu is right to consult the Linux documentation to see what the implementation defines.  But he is being misled by that documentation, which is inconsistent and not up-to-date.

Two years before these three answers were written, and fast coming up to three years ago at the time of first writing this answer, the Linux kernel changed.  The systemd developers added the ability for processes to set themselves up as "subreapers".  From Linux 3.4 onwards processes can issue the `prctl()` system call with the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` option, and as a result they, not process #1, will become the parent of any of their orphaned descendant processes.  The [man page for `prctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html#DESCRIPTION) is up-to-date, but other man pages have not been brought up to date and made consistent.

In version 10.2, FreeBSD gained the same ability, extending its existing [`procctl()`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procctl&sektion=2) system call with `PROC_REAP_ACQUIRE` and `PROC_REAP_RELEASE` options.  It adopted this mechanism from DragonFly BSD; which gained it in version 4.2, originally named `reapctl()` but renamed during development to `procctl()`.

So there are exceptions, and fairly prominent ones:  On Linux, FreeBSD/PC-BSD, and DragonFly BSD, the parent process of orphaned children is set to the nearest ancestor process of the child that is marked as a subreaper, or process #1 if there is no ancestor subreaper process.  Various daemon supervision utilities — including systemd (the one whose developers put this into the Linux kernel in the first place), upstart, and the nosh `service-manager` — already make use of this.

If such a daemon supervisor is not process #1, and it spawns a service such as an interactive login session, and in that session one does [the (quite wrongheaded) trick of attempting to "daemonize" by double-`fork()`ing](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408151852/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html), then one's process will end up as a child of the daemon supervisor, not of process #1. Expecting to be able to directly spawn daemons from within login sessions is a fundamental mistake, of course.  But that's another answer.

### Further reading

- Jonathan Corbet (2012-03-28). [*3.4 Merge window part 2*](https://lwn.net/Articles/488131/). LWN.
- ["4. Various core changes"](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4#head-669b0cddccfb9794868a04b2bccdc2bbf9bc0f9e). *Linux 3.4*. Kernel newbies.  2012.
- [Daemonizing and Upstart](https://blog.nekoconeko.nl/blog/2014/11/12/daemonizing-and-upstart.html). Nekoconeko. 2014-11-12.
- Lennart Poettering (2012-03-23). [prctl: add PR_{SET,GET}_CHILD_SUBREAPER to allow simple process supervision](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ebec18a6d3aa1e7d84aab16225e87fd25170ec2b).  linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git.
- Matthew Dillon (2014). [Add reapctl() system call for managing sub-processes (3) -> procctl()](https://gitweb.dragonflybsd.org/dragonfly.git/commit/fc3bc2868ad212f3b412ad13f0eaa35b3f8d458d). dragonfly.git.
- [`procctl()`](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=procctl&section=2). DragonFly BSD Manual pages. § 2.
- [*DragonFly BSD 4.2 Release Notes*](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/release42/). 2015-07-29.
- Konstantin Belousov (2014-12-01). [*Process reapers*](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-arch/2014-December/016437.html).  freebsd-arch mailing list.

Comment: I had actually noticed orphan processes getting attached to a session init (on Ubuntu with Upstart), but never realised its significance. +1

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194208/5132 for more on upstart session init, specifically.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/exit.html) man page from The Single UNIX® Specification, Version 2:

> The parent process ID of all of the calling process' existing child processes and zombie processes is set to the process ID of an implementation-dependent system process. That is, these processes are inherited by a special system process.

For most Unix variants, that special process is `init` (PID 1).

The Linux [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) man page confirms this:

> If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by init(8), which automatically performs a wait to remove the zombies.

The FreeBSD [`wait(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wait&sektion=2), NetBSD [`wait(2)`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wait+2), OpenBSD [`wait(2)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=wait&sec=2) and Mac OS X [`wait(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/wait.2.html) man pages confirm this too:

> If a parent process terminates without waiting for all of its child processes to terminate, the remaining child processes are assigned the parent process 1 ID (the init process ID).

The Oracle Solaris 11.1 [`wait(3C)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29034/wait-3c.html) man page confirms this too:

> If a parent process terminates without waiting for its child processes to terminate, the parent process ID of each child process is set to 1, with the initialization process inheriting the child processes; see [`Intro(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/intro-2.html).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so.  It always goes to the init process.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process