# Change the parent process of a process?

Tags: process, gnu-screen, job-control, disown

Is it possible to change the parent process of a process? If yes, how?

For example,

- how does `screen` manage to attach a `screen` session and the processes running inside it to different shell processes? Is there change of parent process?
- I seem to heard of other ways of change of shell process in which a program is running, but I don't remember. Is there also change of parent process of the program?
- I thought `disown` on a process changes the parent process of the process, simply because the name `disown` implies that. But I found it is not true.
- Emacs client can attach to emacs server on a different terminal tab. Is there change of parent process?

Comment: `disown` just removes a given child from a shell's internal list of child processes. The child's PPID remains that of the shell. The shell has forgotten that it ever started that child, but the kernel remembers.

Comment: Does the process remember its parent?

Comment: If it wants to know, it calls `getppid(2)`, a system call, and system calls are handled by the kernel. A program could be confused by issuing that call, saving the value, and then using that value after its parentage has changed. There is a chance of a race condition here.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting new kernel feature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The parent process id (ppid) of a process cannot be changed outside of the kernel; there is no setppid system call. The kernel will only change the ppid to (pid) 1 after the processes parent has terminated - if the process did not respond to a signal that the parent was terminated.  For this to happen, the process needs to have ignored various signals (`SIGHUP`, `SIGTERM`, etc.) beforehand.

`screen(1)` has a very elegant means of handling detaching and reattaching.  When you first start `screen`, you are actually starting a user interface (ui), which by default will create a daemon (the session manager).  This daemon has no terminal associated with it, a new process group (`setpgrp(2)`), a new session id (`setsid(2)`).  The daemon, running as `SCREEN`, will then create subprocesses connected to pseudo-terminals (`pty`), then multiplexes the data from the ptys and the ui (`screen`).  The subprocesses think they are talking with a real terminal.

If the ui `screen` terminates, the daemon `SCREEN` will still be running, buffering data, handling signals, waiting for a new ui, etc. because it is a different process group and in its own session.  When you reattach with a new ui `screen`, then the daemon will continue to multiplex as it was doing before.  The daemon will run continue running until all subprocesses terminate, is killed, a fatal bug is encountered or the host reboots.

Comment: Thanks. I added "Emacs client can attach to emacs server on a different terminal tab. Is there change of parent process?"

Comment: Every process has only one parent, until either the parent dies or it dies.  If it dies, the point is moot.  If the parent dies, then the PPID becomes 1, the `init` process.  This is the only time the parent process would change - when the parent process terminates.  Connecting via interprocess communication (pipes, sockets, etc.) has no affect on the PPID.

Comment: How does Emacs attach a client to a server in different terminal tabs?

Comment: The server would listen on a socket (usually a UNIX domain socket file) waiting for connections.  The client(s) would open a connection on that socket.  Tabs are irrelevant to the communication between the client and the server, it could different tabs, different teminal emulates (xterm vs rxvt vs terminal), or could be xemacs.  Each client knows where to connect, so it could be from anywhere.

Comment: The parent process ID does not always become 1.  [This received wisdom absolutism has been wrong for over 3 years, now.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132)

Comment: Thanks, Arcege!  (1) When detach a screen session (reattachable later), what happen to the subprocess(es) running in the screen session and the screen session process? (2) when reattach a detached screen session, are the reattached screen session process and its subprocess(es) are the same as those before detaching? (3) Do you have some reference about what you said about screen, its manual doesn't say things like that, or I miss it?

Comment: Nothing happens to the subprocesses, they continue on as nothing has changed for them.  If you are reattaching, then yes, the same server process and subprocesses will be connected to.  You can tell `screen` to create a new session with new subprocesses, but then you wouldn't be reconnecting.  Most of the reference is the source code itself.  There is an info doc (`info screen`) with a bit more information, but not to the depth in this discussion.

Comment: Thanks. Arcege. (1) Do `screen` daemon and ui communicate by interprocess communication (such as socket)? Does `screen` daemon runs a server, and a `screen` ui runs a client? (2) For emacs, does an emacs server run as a daemon, and an emacs client run as a ui? (3) Do `screen` (daemon and ui) and `emacs` (server and client) work in the same way?

Comment: I can't speak well for `emacs`; haven't really used it in 25 years.  As far as I remember, it connected to an already running emacs process, so it wasn't able to run in the background like `screen`.  To answer your first question: Yes, there is a UNIX domain socket that is used to access the server `SCREEN` process.  Some systems have it in `/tmp/screen/` others may be in `/var/run/screen`; when you run `screen -ls`, you'll see the directory ("1 Socket in /path/to/directory").