# What is a "subreaper" process?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, process-management

The word "subreaper" is used in some answers. Searching Google also turn up entries where the word is "just used".

How can I understand what a "subreaper" is?

Comment: I never heard the word before. Can you include some references for context?

Comment: Here's one: I used it in an answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132 .

Comment: Related question that perhaps I should have posted here instead of at serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/747070/systemd-failed-to-make-us-a-subreaper-invalid-argument-ssh

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This was implemented to the [Linux kernel 3.4](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4#head-669b0cddccfb9794868a04b2bccdc2bbf9bc0f9e) as a flag of the system call [prctl()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html).

From the `prctl(2)` manpage:

> [...] A subreaper fulfills the role of `init(1)` for its descendant
>   processes. Upon termination of a process that is orphaned (i.e., its
>   immediate parent has already terminated) and marked as having a
>   subreaper, the nearest still living ancestor subreaper will receive a
>   `SIGCHLD` signal and be able to `wait(2)` on the process to discover its
>   termination status.

A process can define itself as a subreaper with `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER)`. If so, it's not `init` (PID 1) that will become the parent of orphaned [child processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process), instead the nearest living grandparent that is marked as a subreaper will become the new parent. If there is no living grandparent, `init` does.

The reason to implement this mechanism was that userspace service managers/supervisors (like [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)) need to track their started services. Many services daemonize by double-forking and get implicitly [re-parented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) to PID 1. The service manager will no longer be able to receive the `SIGCHLD` signals for them, and is no longer in charge of reaping the children with [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). All information about the children is lost at the moment PID 1 cleans up the re-parented processes. Now, a service manager process can mark itself as a sort of "sub-init", and is now able to stay as the parent for all orphaned processes created by the started services. All `SIGCHLD` signals will be delivered to the service manager.

In Linux, a daemon is typically created by [forking](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) twice with the intermediate process exiting after forking the grandchild. This is a common technique to avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). The init script calls a child. That child forks again and thus exits immediately. The grandchild will be adopted by `init`, which continuously calls `wait()` to collect the exit status of his children to avoid zombies. With the concept of subreapers, the userspace service manager now becomes the new parent, instead of `init`.

Comment: So, can I think that the process "reap" the "sub"-process? Or, the process is a "sub"reaper because the "main"reaper is init? 
Just trying to think how the term was coined.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Following the [Linux kernel 3.4](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4#head-669b0cddccfb9794868a04b2bccdc2bbf9bc0f9e) link above, the [commit comment](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ebec18a6d3aa1e7d84aab16225e87fd25170ec2b)  for this implementation has further details. (Awed by the details hidden in a git comment)