# Why when a parent dies the child's parent gets set to systemd?

Tags: process, c, process-management

I have been reading the book "Understanding the Linux Kernel" and it has a chapter in it that claims if the parent process dies before the child process, the child's parent will be set to the `init` process with the PID of `1`. But when I actually test it out, I find out it's set to the process with the name `systemd` and its PID is `1702`(which is probably random, and doesnt seem to be constant).

The code I used to test this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 

main() {

    pid_t PID;
    pid_t parentPID;
    pid_t initPID;
    initPID = fork();

    if (initPID < 0) { exit(0); }
    if (initPID == 0) {
            PID = getpid();
            parentPID = getppid();
            printf("Child PID: %d, Parent PID: %d\n", PID, parentPID);
    }
    if (initPID != 0) {
            PID = getpid();
            parentPID = getppid();
            printf("Parent PID: %d, Parent of Parent PID: %d\n", PID, parentPID);
            exit(0);
    }

    PID = getpid();
    parentPID = getppid();
    printf("After death - Child PID: %d, Parent PID: %d\n", PID, parentPID);

}
```

I compile and run the program, and the output I get is the following:

```
[$user]understand the kernel$ gcc child_states.c -o test
[$user]understand the kernel$ ./test 
Parent PID: 7245, Parent of Parent PID: 3698
Child PID: 7246, Parent PID: 7245
After death - Child PID: 7246, Parent PID: 1702
[$user]understand the kernel$ ps -ej | grep 1702
 1702  1702  1702 ?        00:00:00 systemd
 1703  1702  1702 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
[$user]understand the kernel$
```

Comment: Yes, linux has so-called "sub-reapers", look for `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` in the `prctl(2)` manpage. I cannot test it now, but I remember that that was used by systemd.

Comment: Hmm, I get it. so instead of using `init` it uses those so-called sub-reapers? It makes sense, If I look at the parents I get: `init -> systemd -> gnome-terminal -> bash -> executable`. Cool thanks!

Comment: Just tried to remove `systemd` from that chain by killing it and I accidentally crashed my virtualbox haha

Comment: Dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250153/what-is-a-subreaper-process and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149319/new-parent-process-when-the-parent-process-dies/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK systemd uses cgroups to prevent child processes to escape and get attached to PID1 like it used to be with old init systems. And one can keep traceability like that.