# How does systemd handle the death of a child of a managed process?

Tags: linux, systemd, daemon, process-management

How does `systemd` handle the death of the children of managed processes?

Suppose that `systemd` launches the daemon `foo`, which then launches three other daemons: `bar1`, `bar2`, and `bar3`. Will `systemd` do anything to `foo` if `bar2` terminates unexpectedly? From my understanding, under Service Management Facility (SMF) on Solaris `foo` would be killed or restarted if you didn't tell `startd` otherwise by changing the property `ignore_error`. Does `systemd` behave differently?

Edit #1:

I've written a test daemon to test `systemd`'s behavior. The daemon is called `mother_daemon` because it spawns children.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout << "Hi! I'm going to fork and make 5 child processes!" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
      {
    cout << "I'm the parent process, and i = " << i << endl;
      }
    if (pid == 0)
      {
      // The following four lines rename the process to make it easier to keep track of with ps
    int argv0size = strlen(argv[0]);
    string childThreadName = "mother_daemon child thread PID: ";
    childThreadName.append( to_string(::getpid()) );
    strncpy(argv[0],childThreadName.c_str(),argv0size + 25);

    cout << "I'm a child process, and i = " << i << endl;
    pause();
    // I don't want each child process spawning its own process
    break;
      }
    }
  pause();
  return 0;
  }
```

This is controlled with a `systemd` unit called `mother_daemon.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing how systemd handles the death of the children of a managed process
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/my_user/test_program/mother_daemon
Restart=always
```

The `mother_daemon.service` unit is controlled by the `mother_daemon.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A target that wants mother_daemon.service
Wants=mother_daemon.service
```

When I run `sudo systemctl start mother_daemon.target` (after `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`) I can see the parent daemon and the five children daemons.

Killing one of the children has no effect on the parent, but killing the parent (and thus triggering a restart) does restart the children.

Stopping `mother_daemon.target` with `sudo systemctl stop mother_daemon.target` ends the children as well.

I think that this answers my question.

Comment: What happens when you test this situation with example services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It doesn't.

The main process handles the death of its children, in the normal way.

This is the POSIX world.  If process A has forked B, and process B has forked C, D, and E; then process B is what sees the `SIGCHLD` and `wait()` status from the termination of C, D, and E.  Process A is unaware of what happens to C, D, and E, and this is irrespective of systemd.

For A to be aware of C, D, and E terminating, two things have to happen.

- A has to [register itself as a "subreaper"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132).  systemd does this, as do various other service managers including upstart and the nosh `service-manager`.
- B has to `exit()`.  Services that [foolishly, erroneously, and vainly](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotBackgroundise) try to "dæmonize" themselves do this.

(One can get clever with `kevent()` on the BSDs.  But this is a Linux question.)

Comment: this answer is not correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd/3743145

Answer (score 3):

`systemd` has the concept of a main process. In the systemd documentation this is referred to as the "main service process" or simply the "main process".

Example 4 in the [systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) describes have the main process is calculated when `Type=forking`.

[The documentation for `Restart=` in the systemd.service docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) describe the different possibilities for when a service is started in relation to the main process.

Here's the key text from "example 4" linked above:

> systemd will consider the service to be in the process of
>   initialization while the original program is still running. Once it
>   exits successfully and at least a process remains (and
>   RemainAfterExit=no), the service is considered started.
>
> Often, a traditional daemon only consists of one process. Therefore,
>   if only one process is left after the original process terminates,
>   systemd will consider that process the main process of the service. In
>   that case, the $MAINPID variable will be available in ExecReload=,
>   ExecStop=, etc.
>
> In case more than one process remains, systemd will be unable to
>   determine the main process, so it will not assume there is one. In
>   that case, $MAINPID will not expand to anything. However, if the
>   process decides to write a traditional PID file, systemd will be able
>   to read the main PID from there. Please set PIDFile= accordingly.

Comment: Is there an advantage in using `Type=forking` if the original daemon does _not_ die? I understand the advantage if the original daemon forks and then dies, but my daemon forks and stays alive to keep forking at a later time.

Note: I know that this isn't the "systemd way". Ideally systemd would manage **all** the processes, but in my particular case that's not possible.

Comment: That's a separate question. :)