# How do user-created daemons get caught by the systemd user instance?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, daemon

When using a systemd user instance (`systemd --user`), every user-created daemons are owned by this instance.
For example:

1. Let's create a daemon: `nohup sleep 100 0<&- &>/dev/null &`. It has PID `12549`. Kill the parent terminal process (or directly the shell) so that it becomes a daemon
2. The new parent of the process is the systemd user instance:

   ```
   UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   phylliade   12549 20280  0 17:21 ?        00:00:00 sleep 100
   phylliade   20280     1  0 09:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
   ```

So, how is this happening? When a process parent dies, the kernel normally assigns init (here the main systemd) as its new parent; Is the system systemd then assigning the daemon to the user systemd?

Comment: read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250153/what-is-a-subreaper-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Kill the parent […] so that it becomes a daemon

No it doesn't.  A dæmon is not associated with a controlling terminal or a login session.  A process running via `nohup` most definitely still is.  After all, if it were not, there would be no point to the gynmastics of *ignoring controlling terminal hangup*.

> When a process parent dies, the kernel normally assigns init […] as its new parent

No it doesn't.  It assigns the nearest ancestor process that was marked as a child process reaper, falling back to process #1 if there is no such ancestor process.  The world has changed.

Upstart, the nosh toolset's `service-manager`, and systemd all make use of this.  Per-user service management in all three involves local reapers.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132
- [How does systemd handle the death of a child of a managed process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312491/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390089/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`local-reaper`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/local-reaper.html). nosh toolset manual pages. Softwares.

Comment: I meant kill the terminal emulator process (which also kills the shell), editing