# Forking from a systemd service

Tags: systemd, daemon, fork

I have a python program that runs as a systemd user service. From that program, I launch external commands via `subprocess.Popen(cmd, close_fds=True, start_new_session=True)`. My intention is for these new processes to stay running even after the parent service stops or restarts. This works completely fine when I run my program directly from the terminal, but when it's run as a systemd service, these processes get killed along with the parent program upon service restart.

I tried `nohup` and double forking to no avail. I noticed that when double forking, the child process ends up having the `systemd --user` as a parent, not `init` as is the case when run simply from a terminal.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better way for a systemd service to launch external programs so that they're independent from it? Let me know if there's more info I should provide.

Comment: I've not tried doing this, but I would suggest doing a `setsid(2)` call in the child process to create a new process group and session leader.

Comment: @StephenHarris the `start_new_session` argument calls setsid in the child process. Even calling it myself (as part of the double fork) didn't help... that is, not when run as a systemd service.

Comment: How exactly do you start the service? Are you using `systemd-run`, or do you have a service file? If you have a service file, could you share its content?

Comment: See also: [How do user-created daemons get caught by the systemd user instance?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439294/how-do-user-created-daemons-get-caught-by-the-systemd-user-instance)

Comment: @aviro Thank you! Both links are great, I wish I'd found these questions before asking. `KillMode=process` solves my problem.

Comment: In your `[Service]` section use `Type=forking`.  See `man systemd.service` for details, and also check `KillMode=` in `man systemd.kill`.