# Is there the possibility to set a parent process when creating a new process?

Tags: process, process-management

I'd like to set the parent of a newly started process, is that possible?

Example, let us assume that we start a new desktop environment session via a login manager, so our process tree would look something like this:

```
init
 \- login-manager
     \- de-session
```

Now I do have a script to launch my most essential applications which should start with the session, for various reasons I'd like to keep these as a script and not migrate them to the autostart manager of any DE. It looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

application1 &
application2 &
application3 &
```

After running this automatically at the start of the session, our process tree looks like this:

```
init
 |- application1
 |- application2
 |- application3
 \- login-manager
     \- de-session
```

But what I'd actually like is to "reparent" these processes under the session, like this:

```
init
 \- login-manager
     \- de-session
         |- application1
         |- application2
         \- application3
```

So, is there any way to "reparent" a process under another one?

Answer (score 2):

On a few systems, you can mark a process as a *child subreaper*, which makes it take `init`'s role of adopting orphan processes for all its descendants.

On Linux, that's done with the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` `prctl()`.

So, you could start your `de-session` as (here hardcoding the value of `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` for Linux):

```
perl -e 'require "syscall.ph";
         syscall(&SYS_prctl,36,1) >= 0 or die "cannot set subreaper: $!";
         exec("de-session");'
```

But `de-session` might get confused when it receives SIGCHLD signals for processes it has never spawned. Your `init` has been designed to deal with those, but probably not your `de-session`, so you may find that you get an army of zombies as `de-session` never acknowledges the death of those processes it never wanted to inherit.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this with TrueOS (formerly known as PC-BSD) just under a year ago.

## vanilla TrueOS

On vanilla TrueOS, the `pcdm` service runs the graphical user interface.

- The Mewburn `rc` system runs the `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/pcdm` script, which is not long-lived.
- An infinitely-looping and quite convoluted shell script named `PCDMd` spawns `xinit` telling it to run a program named `PCDM-session`.
- `PCDM-session` is a desktop chooser and login program that writes out a nonce shell script in `/tmp`.  It spawns `/usr/local/share/PCDM/pcdm-session`.  It also spins off and orphans a `dbus-daemon`, run as the superuser, on the side if it isn't passed information about a Desktop Bus to talk to.
- `/usr/local/share/PCDM/pcdm-session` chains to `sh /tmp/PCDM-session.blah`, the script written out earlier.
- Said shell script in its turn runs everything in `$HOME/.xprofile`, which is where all of the things such as `gpg-agent` are forked off, and finally runs the chosen desktop's session via `dbus-launch` (run as the logged-in user and spinning off another `dbus-daemon` process).

This results in a fairly messy process tree, both for anything forked off by `$HOME/.xprofile` (which runs everything from `/usr/local/share/pcbsd/xstartup/`) and for anything started under the desktop session process and later orphaned via fork-and-exit-parent (like, alas, `thunderbird`).  All of the D-Bus brokers are not pretty, either; a lot of stuff ends up with process #1 as its parent process ID.  The naming does not help make this straighforward, either.  `pcdm` invokes `PCDMd` invokes `PCDM-session` invokes `pcdm-session` invokes `PCDM-session.blah`.

([I tried to let the TrueOS people know that this was unnecessarily complex](https://github.com/trueos/trueos-core/issues/261), especially the wholly unnecessary hidden extra, and broken, service manager inside the `PCDM-session` program that I have left out of the above description.)

## `local-reaper` and `userenv` from the nosh toolset

In [the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/) there is a little chain-loading utility named `local-reaper`.  Its sole task is to mark (or un-mark) itself as a *subreaper* and then chain-load another program image in the same process.

There's nothing Linux-specific about it, [the subreaper mechanism being available on several operating systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132).  It works on Linux and FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFlySBD, and has no hard-wired system call numbers or anything of that sort.  ☺

Also in the nosh tool set are the `userenv` and `setuidgid` tools.  These actually do *everything* that the TrueOS `pcdm-session` program does, and more besides, including setting up the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable to point to the per-user Desktop Bus broker.  The entire TrueOS `pcdm-session` program is in fact replaceable with

```
#!/bin/sh -
exec >>"$5" 2>&1 
chown -v -h -- "$1" "${XAUTHORITY}"
exec \
local-reaper true \
setuidgid --supplementary "$1" \
userenv --set-path --set-other --set-tools --set-timezone --set-locale --set-xdg \
sh "$4"
```

## putting `local-reaper` to use

To use it, I had to find processes that satisfied three conditions:

- They had to be an indirect parent of the processes that were getting orphaned.
- They had to be long-lived.
- They had to be amenable to suddenly gaining child processes that they weren't expecting.

Not all processes were suitable.  I actually uncovered a bug in the TrueOS `PCDM-session` program, where it was waiting for the wrong process ID, whilst diagnosing whether the `PCDM-session` process was suitable to be a subreaper.

([I told the TrueOS people about this bug, too.](https://github.com/trueos/trueos-core/issues/260)  It's actually a *one character* typing error.)

Fortunately, shell programs almost always *are* suitable to be reapers, and there were several shell processes in this tree.  So also, it turned out, was `xinit`.

## improved process tree

So what happens *now* is;

- I run things under a proper service manager.  The server manager process is *itself* a subreaper.
- Service management spawns a significantly shorter shell script that spawns `local-reaper true xinit …`, making the `xinit` process a subreaper too.
- `xinit` is told to run `local-reaper true helper-script`, making the shell interpreter that interprets *helper-script* a third subreaper.
- *helper-script* runs `dbus-launch --exit-with-session PCDM-session`. It sticks around, running a shell interpreter, waiting for the `PCDM-session` process to finish.  `dbus-launch` spins off two side-processes that it orphans.
- `PCDM-session` cannot be made a subreaper.  Its behaviour is unchanged: it writes out a nonce shell script in `/tmp` and spawns `/usr/local/share/PCDM/pcdm-session`.  But the spinning off of the Desktop Bus side-processed has already been done for it.
- The revised `/usr/local/share/PCDM/pcdm-session` marks itself as a subreaper and chains to `sh /tmp/PCDM-session.blah`, the script written out earlier.
- Said shell script in its turn still runs everything in `$HOME/.xprofile` and thus everything in `/usr/local/share/pcbsd/xstartup/`, and finally runs the chosen desktop's session, but directly and no longer via `dbus-launch`.  It sticks around, running a shell interpreter, waiting for the desktop's session process to finish.

The effects of this are as follows:

- Stuff forked off from any of the scripts in `/usr/local/share/pcbsd/xstartup/` is reparented to the process running `sh /tmp/PCDM-session.blah`.
- Desktop applications such as `thunderbird` that are run via fork-and-exit-parent as grandchildren of the desktop session process are reparented to the process running `sh /tmp/PCDM-session.blah`.
- The side processes forked off and orphaned by `dbus-launch` are re-parented to the `helper-script` process.
- There is no user `dbus-daemon` side process forked off; as everything is pointed to a per-user Desktop Bus broker that is running in another part of the process tree, as a user-level service under proper service management.
- Nothing gets as far as being reparented to `xinit`.  Making it a subreaper turned out to be unnecessary.

The process tree, starting from process #1, looks like this:

```
/sbin/system-manager --
|-- cyclog --max-file-size 262144 --max-total-size 1048576 . (system-manager)
`-- service-manager (system-manager)
  …
  |-- per-user-manager
  | |-- cyclog --max-file-size 262144 --max-total-size 1048576 .
  | `-- service-manager
  |   |-- cyclog JdeBP/socket-servers/
  |   |-- cyclog JdeBP/dbus-servers/
  |   |-- dbus-daemon --config-file ./per-user.conf --nofork --address=unix:path=/run/user/JdeBP//bus
  …
  |-- /bin/sh - ./helper run
   `-- xinit /bin/exec local-reaper true ./helper session -- :0 -auth -retro
     |-- X :0 -auth -retro (Xorg)
     `-- /bin/sh - ./helper session
       |-- PCDM-session -once
       | `-- PCDM-session -once
       |   `-- sh /tmp/PCDM-session.ca1015
       |     |-- /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent …
       |     | `-- scdaemon --multi-server
       |     |-- /usr/local/bin/lxsession -s LXDE
       |     | |-- openbox --config-file …
       |     | |-- lxpanel --profile LXDE
       |     | |-- pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
       |     | `-- xscreensaver -no-splash
       |     |-- /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
       |     |-- life-preserver-tray
       |     |-- /usr/local/bin/pc-systemupdatertray
       |     |-- zeitgeist-datahub
       |     |-- pc-mixer
       |     |-- pc-mounttray
       |     |-- /usr/local/libexec/menu-cache/menu-cached …
       |     `-- thunderbird
       |-- dbus-launch --exit-with-session PCDM-session -once
       `-- /usr/local/bin/dbus-daemon --fork … --session
```